# Prove limit by definition $\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{3n^2-6n+2}{7n^2+n+5}=\frac{3}{7}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Prove

> $\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{3n^2-6n+2}{7n^2+n+5}=\frac{3}{7}$

i got :

$\left|\frac{3n^2-6n+2}{7n^2+n+5}-\frac{3}{7}\right|=..=\left|\frac{-45n-1}{7\left(7n^2+n+5\right)}\right|$

can i get a hint how to continue from here ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for $n \neq 0$ we have $$\frac{3n^{2}-6n+2}{7n^{2}+n+5} = \frac{n^{2}[3-\frac{6}{n}+\frac{2}{n^{2}}]}{n^{2}[7+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{5}{n^{2}}]} = \frac{3-\frac{6}{n}+\frac{2}{n^{2}}}{7+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{5}{n^{2}}}$$
Can you follow from here?